# How to see all the implicits and their types available at any code point?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I'm working on a Scala Play project migration and due to the many implicits accumulated it becomes a daunting task to figure out the available implicit variables and their types at different points in the code, for example, within a Play Controller's `Action` and right before delegating to a view i.e.

```
@Singleton
class Application @Inject() (implicit
                             val verifier: RecaptchaVerifier,
                             config: Configuration,
                             env: Environment,
                             mat: Materializer,
                             indexView: views.html.index,
                             restrictedView: views.html.restricted,
                             profileView: views.html.profile,
                             loginView: views.html.login,
                             restrictedForbidCookieView: views.html.restricted_forbid_cookie,
                             reloginView: views.html.relogin,
                             googleAuthenticationView: views.html.google_authentication,
                             signupView: views.html.signup,
                             widgetHelper: WidgetHelper,
                             webJarUtil: WebJarsUtil,
                             deadbolt: DeadboltActions,
                             auth: PlayAuthenticate,
                             userService: UserService,
                             authProvider: MyAuthProvider,
                             formContext: FormContext,
                             googleAuthService: GoogleAuthService,
                             recaptchaWidget: recaptcha.recaptchaWidget) extends InjectedController with I18nSupport {
  import scala.concurrent._
  import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  //-------------------------------------------------------------------
  // public
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------
  def index =
    TryCookieAuthAction { implicit jContext =>
      deadbolt.WithAuthRequest()() { implicit request =>
        Future {
          implicit val lang = request.acceptLanguages.head
          Ok(indexView(userService))
        }
      }
    }
```

I'm aware of [Idea's](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/edit-scala-code.html#scala_hints) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to enable implicit hints but sadly it only shows the implicit arguments required by a function and not the implicits available. For example, I'd like to know whether there is a `lang: Lang` implicit available and its type as I'm working on a Play mixed Java & Scala project, this `lang` could turn to be of type `play.i18n.Lang` for the former and `play.api.i18n.Lang` for the later.

Comment: Can you ask `implicitly[play.api.i18n.Lang]`, `implicitly[play.i18n.Lang]`?

Comment: @DmytroMitin thanks! what do you mean with "Can you ask ..." to put a breakpoint and evaluate those expressions? In the OP I'm more looking for some Scala Idea plugin with such static code analysis ... when I manage to run the code of course this would help too.

Comment: No, just writing this in source code and compiling it. If this compiles then implicit is present, if it doesn't then implicit is not present.

Comment: https://kubuszok.com/2018/implicits-type-classes-and-extension-methods-part-4/#debugging-hints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>. You need to hover over place, that needs implicit and then press that combination. It even shows you if you've got conflicting implicits:

[image: InteliJ implicits]

Please also check that [page](https://github.com/ljwagerfield/debugging-scala-implicits-in-intellij#implicit-conversions) for more tips for working with implicits.

Comment: Thank you so much! exactly what I needed. However, looks buggy in my Idea 2019.1 latest version of everything installation as it shows only a small subset of all the implicits.

Comment: I shows only impicits that are in scope. Maybe you're not importing them?

Comment: See the sample in the OP .. in the Controller all the injected instances are implicit still I see only a few in the different nested scopes within the index Action definition.